# How to reference foreign key of lookup table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

My Access database has `MainTable` that includes, among other fields, `Event Description`.

I get the Event Description from another table, `EventTable`, that has two fields, `EventID` and `Event Description`

My form has a combobox that lets users select the "Event Description", and that works okay. But in my VBA code, I have to be able to capture the `EventID` itself.

Is there a way to do that without putting an "EventID" control on the form? (Even an invisible one?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a hidden column on the combobox which you can set up via the control wizard. However, specific design steps include:

1. Under Data tab of Property Sheet, use `EventID` as the `Control Source` of combo box. This assumes form is bound to a record source.
2. Under Data tab of Property Sheet, use a two column SQL query that includes `EventID` (hidden column) and `EventDescription` (displayed column) as `Row Source` with `Row Source Type` being `Table/Query`. You can add more columns with corresponding adjustments to #3 below. Be sure that `1` is used for `Bound Column` or whatever column position aligns to `EventID`.

   ```sql
   SELECT EventID, EventDescription
   FROM Events
   ```
3. Under Format tab of Property Sheet, use `2` (or more for every column in query) for `Column Count` and zero for first item and non-zero for second or more items in `Column Widths` (e.g., `0"; 2"`). Ideally, the widths add up to the total width of combo box.

Altogether, above will hide `EventID` in combobox but show to users `EventDescription` and any choice selected will return the corresponding `EventID` value.

Comment: This was easy, especially since I already had my combobox set up this way. You've taught me that Me.cboEvent returns the `EventID`even if the combobox is showing `EventDescription`. Thanks. So what would I do if I actually wanted to return the `EventDescription`?

Comment: If `EventID` is tied to `EventDescription`, why do you want to return it? Do note: the use of PK/FK in the relational model is to avoid redundancy of data. Avoid saving repetitious info from lookup tables in child tables. Use queries to pull data together. Updateable forms can be bound to SQL queries.

Comment: The Event Description is friendlier for the user to read, so I'd like to display that on the form.

Comment: This solution does just that. The user will see Event Description but hides the corresponding Event ID and this ID will be the the saved value.

Comment: I didn't actually answer your question. I don't know why I'd actually want to return the Event Description -- maybe to use in VBA code or display in a label somewhere. I just suspect that I'll need to know how to do it eventually.

Comment: In VBA you can access values of multiple columns with the [Combobox.Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.column) property. Otherwise use a `DLookUp` to retrieve corresponding lookup values or even an SQL query joined at these PK/FK. Happy coding!